# android clear previous animation state in sliding drawer

Tags: android, slider, android-animation, slidingdrawer, translate-animation

I am using android slider.jar for animation. while opening left/right side menu using this mNav.toggleLeftDrawer(); and mNav.toggleRightDrawer(); with help of slide_left_in and slide_left_out , slide_right_in and slide_right_out for transition xml animations..

here animation are working fine.

my problem. when i click menu from left or right side, drawer is opening, when i click items from left or right side, its going to start a new activity like this both activities items.

while clicking item from left side menu that time, first time new activity are opening. that time, my previous animated drawer is opened state. its does not hiding.
before starting new activity, the previous drawer is closing first, and then only new activity is starting. 
I want directly go to the new activity without showing previous animated state..

I have my sample code link
http://www.mediafire.com/download/475tpnob648u6vc/SimpleSideDrawerExample.zip

Comment: when starting new activity Intent nextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(nextActivity);
finish() ;    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_in_left);

Comment: here i used to clear previous animation state mNav.setAnimationCacheEnabled(false) ;
mNav.clearAnimation() ;
mNav.clearDisappearingChildren();